# Write data to Firebase not working - Cannot convert value of type 'user' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to save my registered data to Firebase but get a "Cannot convert value of type 'user' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'" error. I tried many things but I can't seem to figure it out...can someone help me please? how do it save it?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabaseUI

class EventViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    //outlets for text & image
    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var eventName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var eventDate: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var eventDes: UITextView!



    //Database connection
    let rootref = FIRDatabase().reference()
    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func submitEvent(sender: AnyObject) {

        let name = eventName.text
        let date = eventDate.text
        let text = eventDes.text
        var data: NSData = NSData()

        if let image = photoImageView.image {
            data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.1)!
        }

         let base64String = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

        if let unwrappedName = name , unwrappedDate = date, unwrappedText = text{
            let user: NSDictionary = ["name":unwrappedName, "date":unwrappedDate, "text":unwrappedText, "photoBase64":base64String]
        }

        //Add firebase child node
        let event = FIRDatabase().reference().child(name!)

        // Write data to Firebase

        event.setValue(user.init())

        navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        view.endEditing(true)
        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    }

        //UIImagePickerControllerDelegate methods

        func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
            imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            photoImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        }

        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }

    @IBAction func addPicture(sender: AnyObject) {
        if(UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)) {
            imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera

            presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion:nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have created an instance for your base database `rootRef` and again you are creating one more reference which is not required. And also you have created your user: NSDictionary within `if let` so you cannot access that variable out of scope. Declare your `user` above and then use it. Try this code:

```
    let name = eventName.text
    let date = eventDate.text
    let text = eventDes.text
    var data: NSData = NSData()
    var user = NSDictionary()//declare here
    if let image = photoImageView.image {
        data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.1)!
    }

    let base64String = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

    if let unwrappedName = name , unwrappedDate = date, unwrappedText = text{
        //use your declared dictionary
        user = ["name":unwrappedName, "date":unwrappedDate, "text":unwrappedText, "photoBase64":base64String]
    }

    //Add firebase child node
    //let event = FIRDatabase().reference().child(name!)
    //Do not create one more reference to database

    rootref.child(name!).setValue(user)
    //rootref.setValue(user)

    // Write data to Firebase
    //event.setValue(user.init())

    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: The code fixed the error but a new error occurred... It now says  "NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil' "

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post more logs, debug it and check on which line it crashes.

Comment: Seems like it is for `rootref.setValue(user)` . Just remove that line and modify the above line like : `rootref.child(name!).setValue(user)`

Comment: I changed that but it still occurs... 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil' What do you think is going on?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x036aaa14 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0413fe02 objc_exception_throw + 50

Comment: Put a break point at `rootref.child(name!).setValue(user)` and print your `user` dictionary. Post the print description here

Comment: can we move this to a chat? i put a breakpoint here and it shows NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x035d5a14 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0406ae02 objc_exception_throw + 50
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x034be174 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 948
 3   CoreFoundation                      0x0353d114 -[NSMutableDictionary setObject:forKeyedSubscript:] + 68

Comment: Where is the chat link?

Comment: I can't start one due to my lack of reputation points can you start it?

Comment: Usually So populates for chat but I am also unable to start it. Dont know how to start

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38083681/write-data-to-firebase-not-working-cannot-convert-value-of-type-user-to-expe/38083970?noredirect=1#

Comment: Thats weird...However, do you have an idea what the problem could be? If I add a breakpoint even at the very top of it, it still crashes

Comment: I just want see if the `user` dictionary is empty. Try to change the type to `NSMutableDictionary` and check.

Comment: I tried the NSMutableDictionary option it still crashes haha losing my mind here

Comment: Is your `name` variable has the value? it shouldn't be empty string, check that.

Comment: How do you mean? how do i check or change?

Comment: Please put a break point before the line where it crashes and print `name`

Comment: I don't know at which line it crashes?

Comment: Put breakpoint at `let date = eventDate.text` and print the `name` variable

Comment: It does not print, it keeps giving me the error and the apps shuts down.

Comment: should i just send you the file haha

Comment: Do this: `let name = eventName.text
print(name)
    let date = eventDate.text` and put break point at `let date`. Check your console and tell if it has any value

Comment: I did and once again the App does not show value..It crashes it does not even launch the simulator

Comment: Ok, just tell me this: Are you entering any values in your `textFields` before running this piece of code?

Comment: In the code? or the simulator? cause the code is as is, which is displayed above...

Comment: can I just say your awesome for helping me out here!

Comment: try this : `user = ["name":"Test Name"]
        rootref.child("TestChild").setValue(user)`

Comment: Still crashes...Im about to give up I guess the code just doesn't work.. its been like two weeks now and i still can't connect a simple table to Firebase :(

Comment: Even if i place the breakpoint at the top before all the code it crashes